# Webform issue with captcha

Tags: 8, webforms, captcha

I have created about 11 webforms in my website. Now I want to add recaptcha challenge in all of them.

I have installed the captcha module and recaptcha module. recaptcha is coming in all these forms. The problem is form gets submitted even if challenge is not taken. Below is yml file of a sample webform I have created

```
test_field:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': 'Test field'
  '#required': true
captcha:
  '#type': captcha
  '#captcha_type': recaptcha/reCAPTCHA
```

Comment: Are your webforms Ajax-enabled? ReCaptcha has issues with Ajax-Forms, try disabling Ajax for your forms.

Comment: I am having AJAX enabled forms. It is not working for other forms also..

Comment: I dont know why client side validation can't be applied together with `use AJAX` in webforms @jrockowitz. I need to do many work-around to enable client side validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think reCAPTCHA module provides front-end validation. Have you tried performing front-end validation using reCAPTCHA API? You could try something like this:

```
 $('form').submit(function () {
   if (!grecaptcha.getResponse()) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('<span class="red recaptcha">reCAPTCHA is invalid</span>').insertAfter('.g-recaptcha');}
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @jay-chand for the answer. The issue mainly was because the recaptcha module was not updated. Got a temporary solution `event.preventDefault();` was not working so I hide the submit button and showed a dummy button. Then, wrote client side validation and `grecaptcha.getResponse()` in the dummy button click.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created a webform then you can follow thi step

1. Open this url /admin/structure/webform (Structure -> Webform)
2. Click on "Build" in OPERATIONS column
3. Click on "+Add element" button, there will be seen a list form element, you can select captcha from available element